# How to show month year labels Sencha Touch datepickerfield

Tags: extjs, datepicker, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.3

The date picker component does not Year Month Day label in Sencha Touch. See the screen shot for current and expected output.[image: Current & Expected output]

Is there any way to handle this.

I am using Sencha Touch 2.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set [useTitles](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.picker.Picker-cfg-useTitles) property:

```
useTitles: true
```

to your Picker.

Answer (score 0):

I was using 
        xtype: 'datepickerfield'

So adding this listener with setTitle to true solved this issue.

```
listeners: {
        initialize: function(){
            this.getPicker().setUseTitles(true);
    }
}
```

datepickerfield contains a picker component encapsulated in itself.